# How do I fix this program that adds up all the integers in a list except the one that equals said sum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to solve a problem where I have to enter several integers as an input (seperated by a whitespace), and print the integer that is the sum of all the OTHER integers.

So e.g.:

1 2 3  would give: 3, because 3 = 1 + 2

1 3 5 9 would give: 9, because 5 + 3 + 1 = 9

This is the code I currently have:

```
x = input().split(" ")
x = [int(c) for c in x]

y = 0

for i in range(len(x)-1):
    y += x[i]
    del x[i]
    z = sum(x)
    if y == z:
        print(y)
        break
    else:
        x.insert(i,y)
```

As the output, it just gives nothing no matter what.
Does anyone spot a mistake? I'd be ever greatful as I'm just a beginner who's got a lot to learn :)

Comment: I honestly have no idea what your code is supposed to do. It looks totally unrelated to the problem, as you've stated it

Comment: Things like `1 3 5 9` giving `9` aren't helpful to me, when the previous example is `1 2 3`, so you give the _answer_ as the last character in both examples. Are you trying to do a cumulative sum in your code?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is the problem I'm trying to solve: https://open.kattis.com/problems/sumoftheothers

Comment: Usually it's not required to modify a list while you're iterating over it. Why not use `z=sum(x)-x[i]` if that's what you need? Also, your definition refers to "sum of all the OTHER integers"; but in your code you have `y` which is "sum of all the integers so far, including this one".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's **guaranteed** that one of the integers will be the sum of all other integers, can you not just sort the input list and print the last element (assuming positive integers)?

```
x = input().split(" ")
x = [int(c) for c in x]
print(sorted(x)[-1])
```

Comment: If it's guaranteed that there exists a single integer that equals the sum of all others, then it must be exactly half of the total sum, so you can just `return sum(x)/2`.

Comment: Good idea, but I'd say `return int(sum(x)/2)` since it needs to print an integer.

Comment: Thanks Peteris, that works. PApostol's solution is pretty good too, though I forgot to mention that the input can be a negative integer too.

Answer (score 1):

(I renamed your strange name `x` to `numbers`.)

```
numbers = input().split()
numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]

must_be = sum(numbers) / 2
if must_be in numbers:
    print(int(must_be))
```

*The explanation:*

If there is an element `s` such that `s = (sum of other elements`),
then `(sum of ALL elements) = s + (sum of other elements) = s + s = 2 * s`.

So  `s = (sum of all elements) / 2`.

Comment: I find your solution very interesting it takes O(n) ?
Mine also takes O(n) , I m asking ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi, probably all solutions are inherently in O(n)

Answer (score 1):

If the last number entered is always the sum of previous numbers in the input sequence. Your problem lies with the x.insert(i, y) statement.  For example take the following input sequence:
'1 2 5 8'

```
after the first pass through the for loop:
i = 0
z = 15
x = [1, 2, 5, 8]
y = 1
after the second pass through the for loop:
i = 1
z = 14
x = [1, 3, 5, 8]
y = 3
after the third pass through the for loop:
i = 2
z = 12
x = [1, 3, 8, 8]
y = 8
and the for loop completes without printing a result
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a tricky question and can be done in quick way by using a trick
i.e create a dictionary with all the keys and store the sum as value like
{1: 18, 3: 18, 5: 18, 9: 18}
now iterate over dictionary and if val - key is in the dictionary then boom that's the number

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 9]
d = dict(zip(a,[sum(a)]*len(a)))
print([k for k,v in d.items() if d.get(v-k, False)])
```

Comment: Execute the command `import this` and then read carefully the first 3 statements.;-)

Comment: @MarianD Got it